Depth First Search and Barnes-Hut Algorithm Implementation
I am having an issue in python where I have developed a quad tree class with the idea of implementing the barnes-hut algorithm, however, you will not really need to know much of the algorithm to help me. Essentially, I want to place objects into the quad tree and sort it as such, which works, but each object has its own x,y and mass values, so I want to calculate for each node that contains said objects, calculate the mean mass and positions. To implement this, I decided to do a depth first search of the tree, going through each node until it finds a node of only bodies, in which case it exits the node, calculates the mean mass etc, and repeats until each node has its values, however, my implementation doesn't seem to be updating the nodes. If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated.
quad tree.py:
'''

-----------------
        |
   0    |    1
--------|-------
        |
    2   |     3
-----------------
'''
import math

class Body:
    G = 0.6
    dt = 0.01
    threshold = 0.5
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.xv = 0
        self.yv = 0

        self.mass = 1
    def force_calculation(self, obj):
        dist_x = self.x - obj.x
        dist_y = self.y - obj.y
        dist = math.sqrt(dist_x ** 2 + dist_y ** 2)
        force = self.G * self.mass * obj.mass / dist ** 2

        theta = math.atan2(dist_y, dist_x)

        fx = math.cos(theta) * force
        fy = math.sin(theta) * force

        return fx, fy
    def node_check(self, node):
        s = node.max_x - node.min_x
        distance_x = self.x - node.x
        distance_y = self.y - node.y
        d = math.sqrt(distance_x ** 2 + distance_y ** 2)
        s_d = s / d
        return s_d
    def update_position(self, tree):
        pass


class Node:
    def __init__(self, minx, miny, maxx, maxy):
        self.children = [None, None, None, None]
        self.min_x = minx
        self.min_y = miny
        self.max_x = maxx
        self.max_y = maxy

        self.area = Area(self.min_x,self.min_y,self.max_x,self.max_y)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.mass = 0
    def update_center_mass(self):
        count = 0
        mass = 0
        x = 0
        y = 0
        for child in self.children:
            if child is not None:
                print(child.x, child.y)
                x += child.x
                y += child.y
                mass += child.mass
                count += 1
        x = x / count
        y = y / count
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.mass = mass





class Area:
    def __init__(self, minx, miny, maxx, maxy):
        self.min_x = minx
        self.min_y = miny
        self.max_x = maxx
        self.max_y = maxy

class QuadTree:
    def __init__(self, area, max_depth=10):
        self.area = area
        self.root = Node(area.min_x, area.min_y, area.max_x, area.max_y)
        self.max_depth = max_depth

    def get_quadrant(self, body, area):
        mid_x = (area.min_x + area.max_x) / 2
        mid_y = (area.min_y + area.max_y) / 2
        if body.x < mid_x:
            if body.y < mid_y:
                return 2
            else:
                return 0
        else:
            if body.y < mid_y:
                return 3
            else:
                return 1

    def insert(self, body, node=None, depth=0):
        node = node if node else self.root
        if depth == self.max_depth:
            # Reached maximum depth, stop subdivision
            return
        quadrant = self.get_quadrant(body, Area(node.min_x, node.min_y, node.max_x, node.max_y))
        if isinstance(node.children[quadrant], Body):
            # If the quadrant already contains a body, subdivide and reinsert
            bodies = [node.children[quadrant], body]
            node.children[quadrant] = None  # Reset to None before subdivision
            self.subdivide(node, quadrant)
            for b in bodies:
                self.insert(b, node.children[quadrant], depth + 1)
        elif isinstance(node.children[quadrant], Node):
            # If the quadrant contains a node, recursively insert into it
            self.insert(body, node.children[quadrant], depth + 1)
        else:
            # If the quadrant is empty, insert the body directly
            node.children[quadrant] = body

    def subdivide(self, node, quadrant):
        mid_x = (node.min_x + node.max_x) / 2
        mid_y = (node.min_y + node.max_y) / 2
        if quadrant == 0:
            node.children[quadrant] = Node(mid_x, mid_y, node.max_x, node.max_y)
        elif quadrant == 1:
            node.children[quadrant] = Node(node.min_x, mid_y, mid_x, node.max_y)
        elif quadrant == 2:
            node.children[quadrant] = Node(node.min_x, node.min_y, mid_x, mid_y)
        elif quadrant == 3:
            node.children[quadrant] = Node(mid_x, node.min_y, node.max_x, mid_y)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    area = Area(0, 0, 128, 128)
    tree = QuadTree(area)
    tree.insert(Body(10, 70))
    tree.insert(Body(10, 71))
    tree.insert(Body(70, 80))
    print(tree.root.children)
    print(tree.root.children[0].children[2].children)

traverse.py:
import quadTree
import random

random.seed(12)

area = quadTree.Area(0,0,128,128)
tree = quadTree.QuadTree(area)

bodies = [quadTree.Body(random.randint(1,127),random.randint(1,127)) for i in range(10)]
for body in bodies:
    tree.insert(body)

def recusrive_search(node, arr):
    for leaf in node.children:
        if isinstance(leaf, quadTree.Node):
            arr.append(leaf)
            for child in leaf.children:
                if child is not None and not isinstance(child, quadTree.Body):
                    recusrive_search(child,arr)
                    child.update_center_mass()
                elif isinstance(child, quadTree.Body):
                    pass
                    #print(child)
        elif isinstance(leaf, quadTree.Body):
            pass
            # print(leaf)
    node.update_center_mass()
    print(node.x, node.y, node.mass, node.children)




def s_d_recursion_search(node,body,arr):
    for leaf in node.children:
        if isinstance(leaf, quadTree.Node):
            # first, check s_d
            s_d = body.node_check(leaf)
            if s_d < 0.5:
                fx, fy = body.force_calculation(leaf)
            else:
                s_d_recursion_search(leaf,body,arr)

def s_d_calc(body, tree):
    arr = []
    recusrive_search(tree.root,arr)
    for node in arr:
        node.update_center_mass()
    for node in arr:
        if body.node_check(node) > 0.5:
            fx, fy = body.force_calculation(node)
            print(fx,fy)
        else:
            print("Ignore")

'''
def recursion_search(node):
    try:
        if node.isNode:
            for child in node.children:
                if child is not None and child.isNode == True:
                    recursion_search(child)
                elif child is not None and child.isNode == False:
                    print("Body found at:", child.x, child.y)  # Print out the body coordinates
    except:
        for child in node.nodes:
            if child is not None and child.isNode == True:
                recursion_search(child)
            elif child is not None and child.isNode == False:
                print("Body found at:", child.x, child.y)  # Print out the body coordinates

'''
#s_d_calc(bodies[0], tree)
empty_arr = []
empty_arr3 = []
recusrive_search(tree.root, empty_arr)


#recursion_search(tree.root)

